# Getting started w/ Meteor - Display Collection

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-helper

I new to Javascript and Meteor - and I'm sure I'm making a very basic mistake.

I'm trying to understand how to display the contents of a collection.

This is based upon the tutorial on the Meteor site - I've replaced 'Tasks' with 'sw' which is also the name of my collection

```
 Template.HomePrivate.helpers({

});

sw = new Mongo.Collection("sw");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // This code only runs on the client
  Template.body.helpers({
    text: function () {
      return sw.find({});
    }
  });
}
```

HTML:

```
<template name="HomePrivate">
    <div class="page-container container" id="content">
        <div class="row" id="title_row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h2 id="page_title" class="pull-left">
                    Welcome {{userFullName}}!
                </h2>
                <div id="page_menu" class="pull-right">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <h1>Sight Words</h1>
    </header>
 <p>begin list</p>
    <ul>
      {{#each sw}}
        {{> sw}}
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
    <p>end list</p>
  </div>
</template>

<template name="sw">
  <li>{{text}}</li>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your #each loop isn't display anything because sw isn't defined as a helper:

```
{{#each sw}}
  {{> sw}}
{{/each}}
```

Blaze looks for the helper name when using your #each loop - I think that's where your confusion is. In this case, you want to use the helper you defined above, `text`:

```
{{#each text}}
  {{> sw}}
{{/each}}
```

`sw` hasn't been defined as a helper, so Blaze isn't recognizing it.

Now, `{{> sw}}` is valid syntax because it is defined as a *template* (that is what the > symbol is for). Assuming that your sw collection has a field `text`, your #each loop should properly display now.